# Calling init on WL.JSONStore without repeating previously used options

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a way to initialize() ("re-open") an existing JSONStore collection with the same arguments that were used to create it, without passing them again? E.g. without specifying the searchFields that were set up on its creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, you must always pass the same arguments (search fields, etc). You can open a feature request [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

JSONstore does not provide a way to do what you are asking about - init() doesn't keep any "memory" of the arguments that were previously passed to it, so if you want to re-open a collection, the arguments to init() must be passed again.